# webapp penetration testing on dummy application

Tags: security, testing, web-applications, owasp

does someone know where I can find webapplications, on which i can legaly try my pentesting skills like a dummy application or sth? I heard there were some on the OWASP page, but I cant find any. I'll write my thesis about pentesting web applications, and would like to do some tests.

Thanks,
katy

Comment: A better site to find stuff out. http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is website pprovided by OWASP themselves, which is intended exactly for that. It is called [WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project)

> WebGoat is a deliberately insecure web application maintained by OWASP
>   designed to teach web application security lessons. You can install
>   and practice with WebGoat in either J2EE (this page) or WebGoat for
>   .Net in ASP.NET. In each lesson, users must demonstrate their
>   understanding of a security issue by exploiting a real vulnerability
>   in the WebGoat applications. For example, in one of the lessons the
>   user must use SQL injection to steal fake credit card numbers. The
>   application is a realistic teaching environment, providing users with
>   hints and code to further explain the lesson.